# How can I add a mouse cursor to the flutter rangeslider?

Tags: flutter, slider, rangeslider

Flutter Slider widget has mouseCursor Properties
However, the RangeSlider widget does not have this property.

I want to change the shape of the cursor when hovering the mouse on the rangeThumbShape. What should I do?

[rangeThumbShape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eltKc.png)

Comment: you can wrap your widget with MouseRegion

Answer (score 1):

If You Want to change th eshape of the circule you cna use `SliderTheme` or use global Theme in `MaterialApp`

```
SliderTheme(
    data: SliderThemeData(
          thumbColor: Colors.red,
          thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15)
    ),
    child: RangeSlider(
           values: _values,
           min: 0,
           max: 100,
           onChanged: () {}
    );
 ),
```

[This doc can help you in slidertheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData/SliderThemeData.html)

[This is some example of slider](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliders-demystified-4b3ea65879c)

Comment: Thank you.
I also referred to this document, but I couldn't find a way to change the cursor when I hover the mouse on thumbShape.